# Touchscreen using sound input?

Tags: audio, mouse, touchscreen

i don't really know if it is actually possible, but i believe that it can be made. How possible is it to make a program that recognizes different sound bouncing from the screen and turn it into a position that will obviously be later fed to the mouse.

I know that it sounds kind of dumb, but lately i've been noticing that a very dull, strong sound is made when touching the screen, and that sound varies when doing so at different positions. Probably the microphone "hears" differently because the screen acts as a drum with the casing. Anyways, what do you think, anyone has any experience programming with sound?

Comment: what do you think on sending ultrasound waves from a known position and detecting variation with microphone/detector?

Answer (score 1):

First of all most domestic touch screens work by detecting pressure based on a criss-cross mesh layer underneath the display layer.

However I have seen an example where a touch interface was interrogated onto a pane of glass, it used 4 microphones to determine the corners, when you tapped a certain part of the screen it measures the delay in the sound getting to each microphone, therefore allowing one to triangulate the touch.

This is the methodology you would use, you don't even need to set up the hardware to test it, you could throw up an interface in VB, when you click in a box it sends out a circular wave and just calculate using the times it takes to reach the 4 points where the pointer is.

**EDIT**

As nikie suggested, drag & drop, or any kind of gestures would be impossible using the microphone method, as the technique needs a wave of sound to detect the input.

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question7161.htm

Comment: You are correct, because the system requires a sound to be able to track and calculate the position any kind of dragging / gestures would  difficult (read: impossible) to implement. This is why most domestic touch screens use a mesh system. http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question716.htm

Comment: you're right, detecting dragging would be impossible to do, and even if detected it would be impossible to determine if the sound actually came from the screen or if it was from a foreign source...

Comment: I wonder if there is a device that will detect vibration instead perhaps. But it's been done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will get you far, but you can investigate the techniques used in MIDI drums for returning various nuances of play.